# Updating the state of a button in a text editor

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, text, editor

I'm trying to develop an app for ipad and I'm using the contenteditable feature. I have created 3 buttons (bold, italic, underline) and when someone taps them they perform the functionality using execCommand. However when the user selects a word that is bold I want to change the state of the Bold icon image so that it lets the user know that the selected text is in bold. This feature is available in programs like ckeditor and tinymce but I want to know how it's done. I know that some people use a timer that checks all the states every second but I don't think that's the right way. Could someone help me with the code or explain how this could be done.

Comment: This question may need retagging, I think this is JavaScript/HTML and would get a better response with those. I won't do it myself as I'm not sure of the appropriate tags to add.

Comment: thanks for the tip jrturton, and I forgot about the accept thing, I'll make sure to do it this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look up the document.queryCommandState() method to find your answer

I believe you pass a flag which returns true or false, such as...

```
if(document.queryCommandState("Bold")){ highlightBoldBtn(); }
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, if I understand you correctly this will work. This is how I did it with my editors. Just add a 'onclick' and 'onkeyup' event to your contenteditable div or textarea like the following

```
// this array is for every button you implement on your editor
var buttonarr = ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline"] 

// here is the onclick/keyup function for your element
function updateButtons(){
  for(var i=0; i<buttonarr.length; i++){
    var buttontype = buttonarr[i];
    if(document.queryCommandState(buttontype)){
      // call function to turn this button "on" or use jQuery
      $('#btn_'+buttontype).addClass('button_on');   
    } 
  }
}
```

If you noticed, what I did was gave each of my buttons the ID of "btn_" with the button flag appended to it. Using CSS I then made a button_on class that styles it accordingly. You may want to simply remove the 'button_on' class from all buttons on each call to updateButtons(), and then add the class back on as it returns true.

Comment: Thanks andbeyond but my problem is that I want the program to let me know if the state has changed or not since I don't know if the selected text is in bold or not.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, very helpful. Isn't there a way to make things better by registering a trigger similar to onkeyup, something like a onstylemodified or onboldstate that fires when the state changes?

Comment: As far a I know there are no events like that, but this should work fine because the only two actions that would really change your text editor is clicking somewhere in the text or typing. Even if the user uses the arrow keys to move between the text, this event will be fired and update according to the text that the carrot is over.